Curl (Windows 10) убрать лимит в 1Гб
В windows 10 есть стандартный curl
curl 8.9.1 (Windows) libcurl/8.9.1 Schannel zlib/1.3 WinIDN
Release-Date: 2024-07-31
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ipfs ipns mqtt pop3 pop3s smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS HSTS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI threadsafe Unicode UnixSockets

Скачивает файл только 1,00 ГБ (1 079 475 196 байт)
как убрать это ограничение?
везде советы для nginx (proxy_max_temp_file_size 0), а как это в винде?

Скачивает что как откуда? Что происходит после скачивания? Почему вы решили, что проблема в curl и винде, а не, например, в кривом сервере? В каком-нибудь линуксе то же самое качается нормально?

через браузер, через менеджер скачивает нормально, файлы до 1гб через curl без проблем.

Ну и да, "1 079 475 196 байт" это 1.005 ГиБ и оно не делится уже даже на 8, так что число выглядит случайным и не связанным с какими-либо ограничениями

Ну в общем у меня 6-гиговый файл скачался без проблем — https://i.sstatic.net/oJgemGyA.png — что намекает на то, что в curl никаких лимитов нету, а у вас какие-то личные проблемы с вашим конкретным компом

Да, пока что не понял, в чём проблема. wget аналогично гиг и отваливается. Размер разный: 1 079 4** ***
